# Importing google sheets file that contains multiple headers (Using R)

Tags: r

I am currently trying to import a google sheets cross tabular file into R that contains 3 headers that I would like to combine (first row= Year / Second Row = Quarter / Third row = Week).

Most packages in R allow you to select only 1 header and allow you to 'skip' rows until you find the observations however I can't seem to find one that allows you to select multiple headers at once.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This sounds like a job for `data.table`, but you will need to include more information, preferably code samples of your attempt to get meaningful help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might read the first 3 rows first (n_max = 3), and create tidy headers from that, then read the rest (with skip = 2), then add your headers to the data. Something like:

```
headers= read_csv (file, n_max = 3)
names (headers) = paste0 (headers[1,], headers[2,], headers[3,])
data = read_csv (file, skip = 2)
names (data) = names (headers)
```

(the code probably needs some debugging, though.)